# Неверное чтение из файла

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Есть код:

```
char buff[512];
streampos m,n=0;
while(reader.good())
{
   reader.getline(buff,512,',');
   cout<<buff<<endl;
   //m = reader.tellg();//120, n=100
   m = n;
   reader.seekg(m);
   reader.getline(buff,512,'\n');
   cout<<buff<<endl;
   n = reader.tellg();

}
```

Вместо того, чтобы вывести из файла:

```
Hello, how are you doing?
Do you, have hobbies?
Do you, have  a girlfriend?
```

Вот такой вот текст:

```
    Hello
    Hello, how are you doing?
    Do you
    Do you, have hobbies?
    Do you
    Do you, have  a girlfriend?
```

Выводит следующее:

```
Hello
Hello, how are you doing?
Hello
, have hobbies?
Hello
u, have  a girlfriend?
```

Делал все по документации, в голове несколько раз прокрутил алгоритм. Что и где я не учел?

Comment: Короче во простое решение, чтобы будущие поколения не мели себе мозг:
   while(reader.good())
    {
      str.clear();
      reader.getline(buff,512,',');
      cout<<buff<<endl;
      str.assign(buff);
      reader.getline(buff,512,'\n');
      cout<<(buff)<<"\t"<< t <<endl;
      str.append(buff);
      cout<<"The resulting string is: \n"<<str<<"\n";

    }

Comment: Вы неверно поняли задание, простым прямолинейным чтением требуемого автору вопроса результата не достичь.

Comment: Вы не поняли, Я и есть автор:)

Comment: Задача была в том чтобы читать слова из словаря в один массив, который затем хешируется, а затем полную словарную статью заносить в другой, из которого потом будут извлекаться данные. Чтобы избежать заморочек с перемещением курсора, которые, кстати, выполняются очень непрозрачно, предлагается такой вот простой метод:)

Comment: Но все равно спасибо Вам что откликнулись на мою проблему

Comment: О_О так зачем Вы тогда сами себе мозги пудрили? :) Ведь простое последовательное чтение вполне Вас устроило.

Comment: А, все понял. Пора спать. Извините.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы делаете совсем не то, что Вам нужно. Продумайте еще раз алгоритм, ошибка минимум в том, что неправильно задаете смещение в файле `m=n`. Вторая ошибка это сам способ чтения из файла, Вы читаете часть текста потом позиционируете указатель- мне кажется это не правильно, читайте файлы как непрерывный поток. 
К сожалению я не сишник- конретными решениями помочь не могу.

Comment: ну, мне хотелось именно с возвратом указателя в его исходную позицию:)

Comment: А Вы точно файл читаете ? А то, может tty ? Для него seek не знаю, как себя ведет. n после tell попечатайте.

Comment: Файл файл. Смотрите, какая логика. tellg должен возвращать текущую позицию а seekg должен мотать на эту позицию в файле (если использовать первый вариант функции), но работает это все так непредсказуемо... В-общем, я решил уже просто напросто забить на это вот и все:)